# work out f(n), the exact number of unit-time operations the procedure requires as a function of the input size n

Tags: algorithm

I have this question to solve, but despite my efforts, there is no result so far.

```
for i  <− 1 to n do
           for j  <− 2 to (n+i) do
                 // a unit cost operation
```

and also

```
for i  <− 1 to n do 
            for j  <− 1 to n do
                           for k <− 1 to (i+1) do
```

Any suggestions for solving it are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: pick some small n (say n = 5), and for each "unit cost operation" put a tally mark on a piece of paper.  Count them.  As you are tallying, you should notice the pattern that you need to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

1st one

first lets format.

```
for i: 1 to n do:
  for j: 2 to n + i do:
    unit
```

now, let's say n=1

- i=1;  j: 2 to 2 = 1 times

total: 1 units

n=2

- i=1;  j: 2 to 3 = 2 times
- i=2;  j: 2 to 4 = 3 times

total: 2 + 3 = 5 units

n=3

- i=1;  j: 2 to 4 = 7 times
- i=2;  j: 2 to 5 = 8 times
- i=3;  j: 2 to 6 = 9 times

total: 7 + 8 + 9 = 24 units

Pattern emerging yet?..

Comment: This looks very helpful, but for n=3 I cannot understand.Shouldn't it be 4+5+6 times = 15 times?